# Add additional Objective to a model (The Bin Packing Problem example) in Google OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, bin-packing

I'm currently learning OR-tools, so I took one of the examples which is ([The Bin Packing Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin_packing))

Now to learn how OR-tools work, I tweak the code a little bit, first instead of common size bin, I changed it so that each bin has a unique capacity.

I did it by replace these:

```
  data['bins'] = data['items']
  data['bin_capacity'] = 100

  ...

  for j in data['bins']:
     solver.Add(
         sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i] for i in data['items']) <= y[j] *
         data['bin_capacities'])
```

with

```
     capacities = [4, 5,15,4,4,6]
     data['bins'] = list(range(len(capacities))) #data['items']
     data['bin_capacities'] = capacities

...

    for j in data['bins']:
    solver.Add(
        sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i]
            for i in data['items']) <= y[j] * data['bin_capacities'][j])
```

And it worked well, now I want the model to not only to find the fewest bin but also if there are multiple ways to get the fewest bin, it will return the least space remain in all bins.

For example, we got these bin: 20,8,9

And these items: 5,5,5,5,4,4

The result is:
bin 20 contains 5 5 5 5

bin 9 contains 4 4

which make the remaining space in all bins is 1

While the better result would be to contain 4 4 in 8

I tried to add additional value to the solver.Minimize() formula like

```
solver.Sum([solver.Sum([data['weights'][i] for i in data['items'] if x[(i,j)] == 1]) for j in data['bins']])
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: did you find a solution? i try Multiple Knapsacks but I get the same result.